# create procedure to delete child table data if parent data is deleted

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

```
create table a (
a_id integer,
a_name varchar2(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (a_id)

)

create table b(
b_id,
b_name varchar2(10),
a_id integer,
PRIMARY KEY (a_id),
FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES a(a_id)
)
```

Comment: If there any foreign key relationship exists then for deleting any record you need to delete child data first and then parent data.

Answer (score 1):

If the children have FKs linking them to the parent, then you can use `DELETE CASCADE` on the parent.

```
CREATE TABLE book
( book_id int not null, 
 book_name varchar(50) not null, 
 CONSTRAINT book_pk PRIMARY KEY (book_id) 
); 


CREATE TABLE bookdetails
( detail_id int not null, 
 book_id int not null, 
 CONSTRAINT fk_book
   FOREIGN KEY (book_id) 
  REFERENCES book(book_id) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete Procedure as you required just change the tables name in procedure

visit https://anzblog.com/2017/04/29/create-procedure-delete-child-table-data-parent-data-deleted/
It will work for you.As per my understanding.